# Best practice for clearing multi select on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, multi-select

On desktop browsers, we have used a method of having a "Clear" or "All" option at the top of the select dropdown. Clicking this triggers a change event on the select which we can leverage to clear the other options.

On mobile devices, however, this event is not triggered until the select interface is closed in the browser. What is the best practice of clearing a multi select in this case?

Comment: what have you tried ?, where is your code

Comment: I explained it. On desktop you can listen for a change event. On mobile devices you can not. This is not a code question. It's about best practice.